# Перевод названий и выражений в программировании

Tags: локализация

Всем привет! Меня заинтересовал вопрос перевода названий и выражений в программировании. Так как же надо переводить названия: по буквам или по транскрипции?
Ява vs Джава
Си плюс плюс vs Си плас плас 
и т.д.
Каково ваше мнение?

Comment: Вопрос чисто философский, и программирования никак не касается. Моё мнение такое: Си плас-плас называют англичане и американцы; а насчёт языка Java я всегда говорю "Джава", т. к. название "Ява" у меня ассоциируется с сигаретами.

Comment: сигареты ява?) обычно мотоцикл )

Comment: @Gorets, а еще остров так называется. Наверное, по названию сигарет: табак для них там выращивают ИМХО.

Comment: "джава" единствено верное произношение названия языка java

Comment: @jmu, Ipse dixit!

Comment: Точно философский, например, Delphi вроде и в английском имеет два варианта прочтения Дельфи и Делфай

Comment: @mikillskegg А полный титул @jmu не опубликуете?

Comment: Magister magistrorum et omnis sapientiae. Подойдет?

Comment: @jmu кто определил?

Comment: определили создатели языка, которые назвали язык джава. а так как это название то это константа. конечно можно читать писать произносить как угодно. по аналогии: можно штаны одевать через голову, но большинство все же по старинке...

Comment: @jmu, конечно, "джава" правильней, но кто-нибудь из создателей языка говорил, что **по русски тоже надо произносить "джава"**?

Comment: уверен что лично они заповедей не делали (называй джаву джавой), но это еще не означает что механизма контроля небыло. Предположим вы работаете с буржуями и вас зовут Евлампий. Ессно буржуи будут читать ваше имя как смогут но никто не будет мешать вам поправлять их. К тому же они будут старатся подражать большинству (стадный эффект). Уверен что был момент в истории когда разработчики языка java были тем самым "большинством" с которого все брали пример

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В большинстве случаев правильно произносить именно оригинальную транскрипцию. То есть "Джава" гораздо предпочтительнее, чем "Ява" ("ДжаваСкрипт" соответствено тоже, по сравнению с "ЯваСкриптом"). То же касается HTML, который все же лучше произносить как "ЭйчТиЭмЭл", а не какое-нибудь богомерзкое "ХаТэМэЭль". 
Среди примеров, режущих слух лично для себя мог бы выделить всякие там "Визуал Студии", "ретурн", "фалсе" и прочее-прочее. Это все желательно читать с соблюдением правил транскрипции.

Как и в любом правиле, есть свои исключения - здесь стоит учитывать, что в русском языке (а точнее, среди русскоязычных программистов) уже имеется ряд устоявшихся наименований, считающихся правильными. Наверное, читать С++ как "Си плас плас" с точки зрения  преподавателя английского было бы правильно, но с точки зрения человека, говорящего по-русски, называть символ "+" как "плас" было бы по меньшей мере странно. Так что в этом случае предпочтительнее "Си плюс плюс". 
Еще к исключению отнес бы слово "рефлексия", которое в оригинале выглядит как "reflection"  и должно звучать как "рефлекшн", но в контексте русских слов все эти "-шн" звучат просто гадко. (но это уже дело вкуса)

Comment: Вы правильно написали, но чаще говорят ЯВА и АШТЕМЕЛЬ. 

Интересно, лет через 10 что приживется?

Comment: А чем плохо "Выжрал Студия"?

Comment: Как звучит HTML по-грузински? "Хатэл-имэл"

Comment: "Выжрал Студия", говорите?) вы ж мне свет истинного знания открыли)) Теперь только так и буду ее называть))

Comment: Что касается "АшТэЭмЭль", то это тоже идет скорее от неграмотности. Здесь имеет место быть попытка читать его на манер латинского языка, но сама аббревиатура HTML пришла к нам из английского, поэтому тут правильнее будет все же английская транскрипция. А что касается Джавы, то вариант "Ява" неправилен хотя бы потому что "Ява" для нас - это остров, сигареты и мотоцикл. В общем, уже достаточно много значений для одного слова. Записывать сюда еще и язык программирования, который в оригинале читается как "Джава" было бы неправильно

Comment: @DreamChild. Авторство не моё. "Выжрал Бейсик (или Васик?)" (c) A. Korchmar.

И ещё: Java (Indonesian: Jawa) is an island of Indonesia. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java)

Comment: @DreamChild частенько называю ява (и не я один), корни названий тем более одни и те же

Comment: но это же не означает, что это правильный вариант. 
    В частности, Википедия авторитетно утверждает, что "Правообладатели торговой марки Java считают, что правильное написание — транслитерация «Джава», и не признают слово «Ява», соответствующее традиционному произношению названия острова Ява". "Правообладателям торговой марки" я склонен доверять в  большей степени, чем кому бы то ни было в этом вопросе

Comment: Правообладатели такие же люди как и мы + у них есть интерес, чтобы у их продукта было особое название...

Comment: люди они, конечно же, такие же как мы, но вот только кому как не им знать, как правильно называется их продукт?

Comment: Они не знают, а пытаются диктовать. Никого ведь не удивляет, что те же географические названия на разных языках разные и было бы странно всех грести под одну гребенку. Мне лично долгое время и до сих пор вызывает неприязнь произношение Xeon(tm) как Зион, а не Ксеон (сравни с названием хим. элемента - xenonum-ксенон).

Comment: Какой интересный вопрос, целая волна дискуссий. А можно как гопник: жаба, пых, Васик и тд. Но на деле, самое главное чтобы тебя другой человек понял.

Comment: @Ъь_,

    Но на деле, самое главное чтобы тебя другой человек понял.


А еще, чтобы слух не резало.

Comment: @avp это тоже верно, но разные люди привыкли слышать по разному, все зависит от слушателя, а хотя... сам себя вогнал в задумья

Comment: @Ъь_, конечно, многое зависит от ситуации, но IMHO надо делать (говорить) так, как сами считаете **будет правильно**.

Answer (score 5):

С баша - если вы говорите java как ява, то тогда говорите jazz как йазь :)

Comment: С баша говорите? Набрал info bash. В тексте jazz искал-искал -- нифига...

Comment: http://bash.im/quote/94640

Comment: @gecube Это неправильный bash. Вот правильный bash:

     GNU bash, версия 4.2.24(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
     Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
     License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

А насчёт job один знакомый рассказывал, что в 70е годы инциденты на курсах по ДОС ЕС были. Слушатели -- мужики, изучавшие в школе/вузе deutsch, преподаватель -- довольно молодая девушка. Краснела, когда кто-нибудь этот оператор читал по-немецки.

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/143279/ - ах, все таки не баш, а твиттер!

Comment: Интересно как же правильнее говорить jabber?

Comment: А вот это высказывание из url в комментарии @Антон Феоктистов мне понравилось:

    Я сейчас говорю о том, что транслитерация не годится, если в target-языке имеется слово с другим значением, хорошо известным носителям речи, и притом совпадающее с итогом транслитерации. Вы же не переведёте «to web itself» глаголом «вебаться», даже если вопрос «а как в русском языке будет» заставляет призадуматься. 

IMHO как раз в тему.

--

Лично я считаю, что писать термины вообще лучше по английски (если еще нет совершенно устоявшегося термина на русском), а произносить (среди своих), как лучше звучит.

Answer (score 3):

Не вижу принципиальных отличий по сравнению правилами перевода/произношения для обычного языка (не языка программирования). Здесь рулят 2 момента:

1. Есть сложившиеся произношения/переводы. Как пример из обычной жизни: правильно произносить названия ам.штата **Texas**, как **Тексэс**, но все ведь произносят **Техас** и все нормально. Таких примеров тысячи. **Си плюс плюс** из той же серии.
2. Есть сложившиеся жаргонизмы, узкопрофессиональные такзэть. Ну как моряки произносят сухопутный **кОмпасс**, как **компАсс** и проч. Это своего рода индикатор принадлежности к узкопрофессиональному сообществу. Я полагаю, что Джава родом отсюда. Java программисты всегда произносят свой язык как **джава**, а прочие лохи как **ява**.

По HTML'у ничего сказать не могу - это надо спрашивать у вебверстальщиков. Я как лох произношу **аштемеэль**

Comment: @Barmaley лохи? чего-то я пропустил, может поясните? Корни слова одни и те же, то что мне oracle приказал говорить джава, меня особо не волнует (по крайней мере на рабочем месте), да может на конфе или еще где-то я и буду говорить джава (принципиальных отличий лично для меня нет). И да я отношу себя к джавистам, как по работе (j2ee), так и душа моя лежит именно к этой платформе

Comment: @rasmisha - если обижаетесь на лоха, значит вы не джавист :) Джаверы они знаете ли стойкие и к тому же у них с чувством юмора все в порядке :lol:

Comment: @Barmaley да я не обижаюсь. Просто юмор юмору рознь. Да и не Вам судить меня.

Comment: @Barmaley В.Луговской (aka vsl aka mauhuur -- см. Луркморе) утверждал, что джава -- религия, а джавописатели -- опасная тоталитарная секта.

Comment: Я согласен быть представителем тоталитарной секты, особенно если рыночная з/п джавописателей выше чем у пхпистов и сишников. Корень злобствований, думаю, находится именно там :)

Comment: В те времена php ещё не был так распространён из-за проблем с безопасностью, а на C++ vsl ругался не меньше, чем на java. Довольно специфический персонаж.

Comment: @alexlz я не понял кого вы имеете ввиду... Луговского или еще кого-то?

Comment: @Barmaley ага. Виталий Луговской (или Луговский?), который aka vsl, aka mauhuur и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Знать нужно все варианты. Но самое главное - нужно знать, в каком обществе какой вариант употреблять. Это значительно лучше, чем доказывать что один вариант лучше другого по какой то там причине.

А вот какой вариант правильный - оставим это лингвистам. Пусть ломают копья.

p.s. Я встречал человека, который твердо уверен, что джава - это java, а ява - это javascript. И попробуй только ему что то подоказывай:)